# Reboot Android devices automatically at a specific time (i.e. 3 AM) every day

Tags: shell, reboot, automation

I have a rooted Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus (A6020a46) running TWRP + Arrow OS. It doesn't provide an automatically scheduled reboot out of the box. None of the apps worked. Also the apps that claim to provide this functionality are suspiciously ad-filled and I'm not comfortable giving root permission to them.

So, here is what I've tried till now:

- SMManager. Didn't work. Also, suspicious app.
- Wrote an infinite loop shell script, but I'm afraid it'll make my system too busy:

  ```
  while true; do
    if [[ "$(date +"%H")" -eq "3" ]] ; then
      reboot
    fi
  done
  ```

  But I don't know how to autorun it on boot and I'm afraid it'll break my Android
- Tried Termux (elevated) with `cronie`

  I'd put `0 3 * * * /system/bin/sh reboot` in `/data/crontab/root` like mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079857/15157999), but `crond` isn't recognised as a valid command in root shell.

Further, the `init.d` directory doesn't even exist, but an `init` directory does with a bunch of `.rc` files.

I've ran `sudo crontab /data/crontab` and then `crontab -l` lists the proper crontab, but it doesn't show up anywhere else. I'm not sure it will work. Further, I'll have to always manually run this (as far as I understand it) and seriously manually rebooting is infinitely easier.

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions appreciated. I'd prefer shell scripts over shady apps.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) since this is quite an uncommon request: why do you need to restart the device every 3 AM? (That said, googling `a6020a446` doesn't return anything).

Comment: sorry it was dumb of me to not notice the spelling error. It is `a6020a46`. Also, I just want to restart my device everyday at 3 am with possibly a shell script. I have shared what I've tried and the outcomes but my original problem still remains, I want to restart my device automatically at 3 AM. This is to have optimal performance and avoid network issues which for some reason appear when my phone has been running for abt 2+ days.

Comment: [tag:automation] is an option. Using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), create a macro with trigger of day /time and action - reboot. If you are OK with apps. You can test it by adding *empty trigger* as another trigger and testing the macro from 3 dots menu

Comment: Why not just write a normal alarm clock app that will run `system("su -c reboot");` (or maybe even call the Android API function for this, if it exists) when the alarm is triggered? Alarm clocks made correctly don't usually suffer from energy saving modes.

Comment: @beeshyams, thank you that app seems good enough and is what I'll probably use for now since I am not technically advanced enough (yet) to implement the other solutions. Nonetheless it is an app, one that perhaps isn't gpl and hence I'm still suspicious of it.especially since it now has root access.

Comment: @Ruslan, I am unfortunately not skilled enough in Android Dev to make an alarm app from scratch. Right now I am only a consumer and a tinkerer with Android devices but not yet a dev. Forget "made accurately", my skills ensure that (for now) I can't even make one. Further I've lots of other work (unfortunately) and I'd rather use a script than write an app from scratch. However I shall look into it. Thanks.

Comment: There are some opensource alarm clocks that you could modify to your needs.

Comment: @Ruslan could you give me some examples which would be easy to modify for an absolute beginner with **ZERO** prior experience with Android programming??

Comment: ok I have pretty much fallen in love with the Macro Droid app. It is fantastic and does exactly what I want. Who knows, maybe it will make me too lazy to actually solve this problem on the cli 

Comment: @beeshyams looks like your answer using MacroDroid helped the OP. Would you like to post it as a proper answer?

Comment: @AndrewT sorry for delay in reverting// I think it's better if the OP does that (being lazy).  Thanks for tracking comments and checking!

Answer (score 3):

Run the following shell script from `init.d` (or `/data/adb/*.d/` in case of Magisk). Or run directly from `init`'s `.rc` file. See [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526)

```
#!/system/bin/sh -e

# ignore signals
for i in $(seq 64); do trap '' "$i"; done

# seconds until today 3AM
SECS=$(( $(date -d '03:00' +%s) - $(date +%s) ))

# if today's 3AM has passed, set it to tomorrow's
[ SECS -gt 0 ] || SECS=$((SECS + 86400))

# wait until 3AM
echo "${0##*/}: sleeping for $SECS seconds"
sleep $SECS

# Reboot device
echo "${0##*/}: restarting"
/system/bin/reboot scheduled-reboot ||
/system/bin/setprop sys.powerctl reboot,scheduled-reboot
```

Comment: doubt it will work, guesswork `sleep` is stretched in idle mode (power saving)

Comment: This answer is interesting, one that I think I'll eventually use. However, I haven't understood completely and shall use it only when I do so. Also could you clarify what @alecxs has said in his comment above?

Comment: @alecxs that's correct. But the process can be added to [`foreground` cgroup](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221420/218526) so that it's not affected by idle mode. That's how services work. Or `sleep` for smaller intervals like 1min and check intermittently if 3AM has passed. Else the only way to wake up the device from idle mode to perform a task at exactly 3AM is to use [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) API from an app. It's not possible with a shell script.